# Android USB debug not listing in "Device choser" mac os android studio 1.4.1

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, usb-debugging

I had a Android studio 1.4(mac os) and was working on my USB device connected. It was working fine for many days. But i downloaded a project which was done in Android 1.5 preview version and imported a project. Gradle asked me to sync to latest version of grade and i did sync. After that i am not able see my USB devices in device list. USB debugging is still on in devices, i rebooted Android studio, mac and tried. Still same result. I toggled USB device mode, tools -> Android -> Enable ADB. I am exhausted.  I am not sure if this issue is anything related to grade sync, but problem is issue started for me after the sync.

Pls help

EDIT:
sudo ./adb kill-server
sudo ./adb start-server
sudo ./adb devices

even, this did not work. devices list only emulator not USB connected device

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what solved my problem, but here is what i did

1. I checked if the device is listed going to Mac OS X, about page
2. Connected to different USB port, assuming that if it could be issue due to USB2 and USB3 connected devices
3. Finally, Once i was waiting for my mobile to show up but it did not showup but when i unlocked my mobile and waited for some time it showed up in device list.

I really not sure about what was the issue...but these worked for me...